# Multiple condition for dropdown list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, combobox

I have this dropdown list

```
<label class="control-label">Type</label><br/>
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="selectChange()" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items">
  <option value=""> Select Type</option>
 </select>
```

this is the list in items.

```
$dialogScope.items = [{
                name:"Pencil",
                value:"0",
            },{
                name:"Eraser",
                value:"1"
            },{
                name:"Colourpencil",
                value:"2",
            },{
                name:"Ruler",
                value:"4",
            },{
                name: "Pen",
                options : ["Blue","Red","Colourful"]
            },{
                name: "Laptop",
                options : ["Dell","Lenovo","Acer"]
            },{
                name: "Pencil Box",
                value:"7",
            },{
                name: "Download CACHE By GPU",
                value:"8",
            },
            ];
```

What is want is that if user choose Pencil **or** Eraser **or** Ruler **or** Pencil Box, label A and Label B field will hide. I tried as below

```
 <div class="form-group has-feedback"  ng-if="type==0||type==1||type==4||type==7" ng-hide="hideField1">
  <label class="control-label">{{labelA}}</label>
   <input type="url" class="form-control" ng-model="stepA" name="stepA" required>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-if="type==5||type==6||type==8||type==10" ng-hide="hideField2">
  <label class="control-label">{{labelB}}</label>
   <input type="url" class="form-control" ng-model="stepB" name="stepB" required>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-if="type==0||type==4||type==7||type==5||type==6||type==8||type==9||type==10" ng-hide="hideField3">
  <label class="control-label">{{labelC}}</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="stepC" name="stepC" required>
 </div>
```

And use this in the controller but it doesn't to be in the right way. Anyone notice the mistake? and if any correct way to create this.

**UPDATED**

```
$dialogScope.selectChange = function(selectedItem){
 if (selectedItem) {
  $dialogScope.type = selectedItem.value;
  $dialogScope.labelA = '';
  $dialogScope.labelB = '';
  $dialogScope.labelC = 'MD5';
  $dialogScope.stepA = '';
  $dialogScope.stepB = '';
  $dialogScope.stepC = '';
   if ($dialogScope.value == 0) {
     $dialogScope.labelA = "APK URL";
    } else if ($dialogScope.value == 4) {
     $dialogScope.labelA = "OBB URL";
    } else if ($dialogScope.value == 5) {
     $dialogScope.labelB = "OBB URL";
    } else if ($dialogScope.value == 6) {
     $dialogScope.labelB = "APK URL";
    }
   console.log($dialogScope.selectedItem)
  };
```

Comment: Where does `value` come from in `$dialogScope.selectChange`?

Comment: @Quill from $dialogScope.items = [{
                name:"Pencil",
                value:"0",

Comment: Try changing `$dialogScope.type = value` to `$dialogScope.type = selectedItem.value`

Comment: @Quill tried but nothing change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.items = [{
                name:"Pencil",
                value:"0",
            },{
                name:"Eraser",
                value:"1"
            },{
                name:"Colourpencil",
                value:"2",
            },{
                name:"Ruler",
                value:"4",
            },{
                name: "Pen",
                options : ["Blue","Red","Colourful"]
            },{
                name: "Laptop",
                options : ["Dell","Lenovo","Acer"]
            },{
                name: "Pencil Box",
                value:"7",
            },{
                name: "Download CACHE By GPU",
                value:"8",
            },
            ];
                 
      $scope.hideMe = function(hideElements){
         if($scope.selectedItem){
            return (hideElements.indexOf($scope.selectedItem.name) != -1)?true:false;
         }
         else{
             return true;
         }
      }
                 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <label class="control-label">Type</label><br/>
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="selectChange()" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items">
    <option value=""> Select Type</option>
  </select>
  {{selectedItem}}
   <div class="form-group has-feedback"  ng-if="selectedItem && hideMe(['Pencil', 'Ruler']);">
  <label class="control-label">{{(selectedItem.value==0)?"APK URL":"OBB URL"}}</label>
   <input type="url" class="form-control" ng-model="stepA" name="stepA" required>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group has-feedback"  ng-if="selectedItem && hideMe(['Pen', 'Laptop']);">
  <label class="control-label">{{(selectedItem.value==5)?"OBB URL":"APK URL"}}</label>
   <input type="url" class="form-control" ng-model="stepB" name="stepB" required>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <label class="control-label">labelC</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="stepC" name="stepC" required>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but can u explain return (hideElements.indexOf($scope.selectedItem.name) != -1)?false:true;

Comment: In this query checking, your selected option exists in array it exists return false otherwise, it will return true

Comment: i updated my question above, i want to display {{labelA}} accroding to if-else statement above. but it doesn't work. any idea?

Comment: what if i want to check the condition in controller? i think the problem is with the if-else statement